# flask postgresql connection pool using uwsgi to run behind nginx

Tags: postgresql, nginx, flask, connection-pooling, uwsgi

I'm relatively new to web servers and web applications.

We have a basic python application implemented on flask which was deployed on the server using uwsgi to run behind nginx server. Currently our app has to create a postgreSQL db connection on every requests which takes more than ideal time. What I need is a persistent connection pool which will be created only once and reused on each request.

I tried to create a connection pool using pssycopg2 built-in functionality

```
# create pool with min number of connections of 1, max of 10
a = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1,10,database='YOURDB', otherstuff...)
```

But Couldn't get a global persistent connection pool to be used, when processing a request, may be because of UWSGI.
I looked up connection pooling with flask UWSGI but couldn't find sufficient information to create connection pools

**Question 1: How or what is the best way to implement connection pooling in such an environment mentioned above (flask + UWSGI + NGINX)?**

**Question 2: If I implement an ORM like SQL-Alchemy. Will that be able to provide efficient connection pooling in the above case or will UWSGI block its capabilities to provide a connection pool?**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few PostgreSQL pooling options:

- [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [PgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer%20PgBouncer)
- [psycopg2.pool](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html)

I'm using psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool with a small Flask app and it is working fine.

```
connection_pool = pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(MINCONN, MAXCONN, database=DB, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)
conn = connection_pool.getconn()
# use conn, then:
connection_pool.putconn(conn)
```

It's up to you to handle what happens when the pool is full, as getconn() doesn't block.